# How can I avoid Partial Changeset hell when branching with TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, changeset

10 developers have been working on $Trunk for a couple of months.
When came time to do a release to production, code from $Trunk was built and deployed.

Now, we would like to implement some form of branching strategy. First thing first, we needed a $Release branch to reflect code that is currently deployed.

So we branched $Trunk -> $Release.
Straight away, I tried merging a specific changeset from $Trunk onto $Release. And I can see merge candidates from months ago. (How can that be?!? - I just merged from that branch!)

I duly looked into the issue and used **tf merge /discard** that brought in more merge candidates. After a few iterations of **tf merge /discard**, I managed to clear it all up - it is a VERY scary process, because I am essentially performing a check-in on the Release branch every time. And I am talking 100's of changesets here.

I would now like to create a $Dev branch - meaning I have to go through the same process. Then from the $Dev branch, I would like developers to create many feature branches. I am dreading the thought...

The problem is obviously at the source ($trunk) - but so far my options have been to resolve the problems in every single branch of trunk.

Git is not an option (sadly).
Any ideas how I could start creating branched from $trunk avoiding the partial merge candidate saga?

Comment: It sounds like certain check-ins contained files that were not scoped to what is now your branch root. They might also check in files in another folder like `docs` or `tests` outside of your trunk folder. After branching, did you convert both `$Trunk` and `$Release` to a Branch? do they have a different icon in the Source Control Explorer now?

Comment: $Trunk is a branch (must have been converted from a folder at some point). $Release is a a branch.

Comment: It is also worth noting that tf merge discard has brought back to life folders that were deleted from the $trunk. So after the whole exercise, I expected $trunk and $release to be identical on disk, but turned out $release had some extra folders that had been deleted from $trunk.